# Clarify voting requirement notification

Tags: feature-request

Can the notification be clarified for up voting and down voting? See attached images for the current notification messages. The up and down vote notifications identify different amounts of reputation points required to cast a vote but can be confusing to a new user.

According to the privileges documentation both values are correct. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges. 125 rep is required to down vote and 15 rep is required to up vote.

I suggest changing the text for up vote to:

> Thanks for the feedback! **Up** votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

I suggest changing the text for down vote to:

> Thanks for the feedback! **Down** votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

[image: Down Voting Notification]
[image: Up Voting Notification]

Comment: Sure. This would be a improvement.

Comment: Or [even better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271920/286591). I've always thought that text is pretty confusing/dumb,

Comment: Interesting link. I too was under the impression my vote would automatically appear after my rep was ≥15. I'll have to wait until I reach that mile stone so I can up vote that suggestion too.

Comment: Also, that's an awfully wide notification. Can't we limit the width such that we don't go over the [recommended characters per line](http://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability)?